# Make import work executed from different path

Tags: python

Imagine having this structure

```
my_run
./dir_a:
    __init__.py
    a.py
./dir_b:
    __init__.py
    b.py
./dir_c
    __init__.py
    c.py
```

a.py containing from dir_b import b

b.py containing from dir_c import c

Is there a way to be able to execute my_run (symlink to a.py) without changing import path by ..dir_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `my_run` need to be a symlink? If not, you could simply define a short script that imports `a.py` from there. Note that any code in `a.py` within `if __name__ == '__main__':` will not execute anymore.

So, to get around this, maybe the following setup can be of use.

**a.py**:

```python
def main():
    # initialization code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**my_run**:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

from dir_a import a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a.main()
```

This might need some tweaking depending on your actual code. Use the shebang line if appropriate.